# How to read config Key/Value pair from file in Go?

Tags: go

I have a low latency app in Node.js from which I am coding a new baseline in Go.

The app in node uses config and some key/value pairs.

In config/index.js

```
var config = {};
config.app = {
    port:9000
};
config.log= {
    level:"error"
}
module.exports=config;
```

And another file config/key_values.js which contains key/value pair and is refreshed every few minutes.

```
module.exports.key_values= {
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2",
}
```

And to read this I just use the below code.

```
let config = require('./config/index');
let keys_vals = require('./config/key_values.js');

console.log('port', config.app.port); //port 9000
console.log('key1 data -->', keys_vals.key_values['key1']); //key1 data --> value1
```

How can I achieve the same thing in go. I have checked [Gonfig](https://github.com/tkanos/gonfig) for config implementation as well as building structs.

What should be better/best way to achieve the same functionalities as I do in Node?

Comment: The file may be rewritten every few minutes, but your node app doesn't reload it on change, does it?

Comment: Yes it does, once its downloaded from scheduled job after interval, a timer runs in the node app which refresh the file. I use this. `delete require.cache[require.resolve("./config/key_values.js")];` though this is not the concern for go implementation, I may restart the app itself to reload the config if required.

Comment: This question is too broad. There are plenty of configuration formats to chose from (json, yaml, toml, ini, etc.) Recommendations would be opinion based. Pick one and come back with a specific question if you're having trouble.

Comment: I did included a sample json config in question and need to know how can I reuse it though with some obvious change. yaml will do as well, just to make sure it works in the same way.

Comment: There's really not enough detail to go on here. Where are you storing t he config? What system has to read it? What _"things"_ will be part of the config? If you're setting the port your service is supposed to listen on, reloading that isn't the biggest of your worries. If your service is HA, on multiple zones/nodes, then you might want to use a K/V store, and updates can be handled in a lot of ways, if it's a config file, you can use fsnotify, or reuse existing things like cobra etc...

Comment: I am converting my node js app to go. So following the same structure will be keeping the both config file and file containing dynamic K/V pair in same config folder. The config will have all the static variable that may change/increase. like storing port, log level, static api url, timeout value, some flag to enable disable logging etc. and the key value file contains the data which will change every few minute hence to put that in different file.and app will just read/refresh(not sure how its done in go, have commented how i did it in node).

Comment: Also the file containing key/value pair generated from the db and downloaded with scheduled job as commented. The basic idea of this 2 file is just config is for app level to which only I (developer) has access and file with K/V is generated say from admin perspective who is using some interface to put some config in db and loaded in the file to be used in app and he can anytime to change that and app should read that after few min of refreshing without changing anything or restarting the app.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So here is what I have done for now.
config/index.js is now config/config.json with content

```
{
    "app":{"port":9000},
    "log":{"level":"error"}
}
```

and  config/key_values.js is  config/key_values.json

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
}
```

And to read this value I am just reading file as `[]byte` and passing the this to `function GetBytes` of library  [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson)

So the final code look like this:

```golang
    configFile, err := os.Open("config/config.json")
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(configFile)
    result := gjson.GetBytes(byteValue, "app.port")
    fmt.Println(result) //prints 9000
```

And same for key values file.

```golang
    configFile, err := os.Open("config/key_values.json")
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(configFile)
    result := gjson.GetBytes(byteValue, "key1")
    fmt.Println(result) //prints value1
```

Also tried using struct before to parse config as described [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/04/load-json-configuration-file-golang-application/). But this gjson library seems to be what I was searching.